# Acumatica Processing Screen Updating ARTran Custom Field Needs To Also Update Custom Table field

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom processing screen that is updating a custom field called UsrDateNotified in the ARTran table where the UsrDateNotified is prior to the RevisionDateReceived in a custom table ItemBaseDocument.  We also need to update the UsrDateNotified field in table ItemBaseDocument which is linked to the InventoryID in ARTran.  Our current code below validates for updating the ARTran table, but we are struggling with how to also update the related ItemBaseDocument for the selected ARTran records.  What is the right approach for this scenario?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Data;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace DocCenter
{
  public class UpdateLastNotified : PXGraph<UpdateLastNotified>
  {
    public PXFilter<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter> MasterView;
    public PXCancel<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter> Cancel;


    [PXFilterable]

    public PXSelect<ARTran> DetailsView;

 public UpdateLastNotified() 
    {
   Cancel.SetCaption("Clear Filter");
   this.DetailsView.Cache.AllowInsert = false;
   this.DetailsView.Cache.AllowDelete = false;
   this.DetailsView.Cache.AllowUpdate = true; 
    }



protected virtual IEnumerable detailsView()
{
UpdateLastNotifiedFilter filter = MasterView.Current as UpdateLastNotifiedFilter;
PXSelectBase<ARTran> cmd = new PXSelectJoinOrderBy<ARTran, 
  InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<ARTran.inventoryID, Equal <InventoryItem.inventoryID>>, 
  InnerJoin<ItemBaseDocument, On<InventoryItemExt.usrDocumentNumber, Equal<ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode>>,
  InnerJoin<Contact, On<ARTranExt.usrContactID, Equal<Contact.contactID>>>>>,  
  OrderBy<Asc<ARTran.tranDate>>>(this);    

cmd.WhereAnd<Where<ContactExt.usrNotificationPriority,
Equal<Current<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter.notificationPriority>>>>();   


cmd.WhereAnd<Where<ARTranExt.usrDateNotified,
Less<ItemBaseDocument.revisionDateReceived>>>();     


 if (filter.BaseDocumentCode != null)
{
 cmd.WhereAnd<Where<InventoryItemExt.usrDocumentNumber,
Equal<Current<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter.baseDocumentCode>>>>(); 
}  

   return cmd.Select();
} 

public PXAction<UpdateLastNotifiedFilter> Process;
[PXProcessButton]
[PXButton(CommitChanges=true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Process")]
protected virtual IEnumerable process(PXAdapter adapter)
{

  PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate() 
  {
  foreach(ARTran tran in DetailsView.Select())
    {
    if (tran.Selected==true)
      {
      ARTranExt tranExt = tran.GetExtension<ARTranExt>();
      ARInvoiceEntry tranEntry = new ARInvoiceEntry();
      tranExt.UsrDateNotified = MasterView.Current.DateNotified;
      tranEntry.Transactions.Update(tran);
      tranEntry.Save.PressButton();



      }

    }


  }

        );
 return adapter.Get();
}




    [Serializable]
    public class UpdateLastNotifiedFilter : IBqlTable
    {

public static class NotificationPriority
{
    public const string None = "N";
    public const string Alert = "A";
    public const string Express = "E";
    public const string Shipment = "P";
    public const string Subscription = "S";
}   


      #region NotificationPriority
      public abstract class notificationPriority : PX.Data.IBqlField
      {
      }  

      [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]
      [PXDefault(NotificationPriority.None)]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notification Type")]
      [PXStringList(
          new string[]
      {
      NotificationPriority.None,
      NotificationPriority.Alert,
      NotificationPriority.Express,
      NotificationPriority.Shipment,
      NotificationPriority.Subscription
      },
      new string[]
      {
      "None",
      "Alert",
      "Express",
      "Shipment",
      "Subscription"
      })]  


      #endregion    





      #region BaseDocumentID
      public abstract class baseDocumentCode : PX.Data.IBqlField
      {
      }  

 [PXString(50)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Document Number")]
[PXSelector(typeof(DocCenter.ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode))]    

      public virtual String BaseDocumentCode
      {
        get;

        set;

      }
      #endregion      



      #region DateNotified
      public abstract class dateNotified : PX.Data.IBqlField
      {
      } 
      [PXDBDate()]
      [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date Notified")]
      public DateTime? DateNotified { get; set; }
      #endregion 




    }




  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a view that selects ItemBaseDocument.

```
PXSelect<ItemBaseDocument> ViewName;
```

In your for loop of your action button, you will want to create a new ItemBaseDocument object and set it equal to the corresponding ItemBaseDocument row entry. You can then update the date of this object, and when you execute your Save.PressButton() action, that should save the updates to that entry as well.

```
foreach(ARTran tran in DetailsView.Select())
{
if (tran.Selected==true)
  {
  ARTranExt tranExt = tran.GetExtension<ARTranExt>();
  ARInvoiceEntry tranEntry = new ARInvoiceEntry();
  tranExt.UsrDateNotified = MasterView.Current.DateNotified;
  tranEntry.Transactions.Update(tran);
  tranEntry.Save.PressButton();

  //Target Added Code
  ItemBaseDocument doc = PXSelect<ItemBaseDocument, Where<ItemBaseDocument.inventoryID, 
     Equal<Required<ARTran.inventoryID>>>>.Select(tran.InventoryID);
  doc.UsrDateNotified = MasterView.Current.DateNotified;

  }

}
```

Disclaimer: There may be a syntax error in the added code above. If there is, please let me know and I will fix it.

Comment: I noticed that you might want to either execute the Save.PressButton() after executing the code I added.